# How to pass object id to another controller rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise, ransack

i have problem 
i pass the object id to one controller to another in between i perform the sign_in operation using devise gem, when sign_in done then next page show the error  "Active record::RecordNotFound BookingController#index" and "Could not found room without an id" 
 ## i perform Action in Step
1: when i browse  to "guest_search" page  i performed  searching  operation using "Ransack gem " when searching  are done i get particular id using  params[:id] and send to another another controller l.e roomcontroller.rb  .

2 :  when sending another controller performed the "before_filter :authenticate_user!" on new controller if user sing_in and render new controller action give error "Active record::RecordNotFound BookingController#index" and "Could not found room without an id"

RoomController.rb

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController   
  def guest_search 
  @search = Room.search(params[:q])
  @roome = @search.result(:distinct => true)
  @room= @roome.where("status IS ?", true).order("room_type_id desc")
 end  
end
```

guest_search.html.erb

```
<%= search_form_for @search, url: guest_search_rooms_path, html: {:method =>:post} do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :start_date_eq , "Start Date"%>   
  <%= f.text_field :start_date_eq, class: 'release_date' %>   

  <%=f.label :end_date_lteq, "End Date" %>   
  <%= f.text_field :end_date_lteq, class: 'release_date' %>   

  <%= f.label :Location %>
  <%= f.collection_select :location_id_eq, Location.all, :id, :locationname, :include_blank => true %>

  <%= f.label :RoomType %>
  <%= f.collection_select :room_type_id_eq, RoomType.all,:id,:room_type, :include_blank => true %>

  <%= f.submit "search" %>
  <% end %>

<table class="table table-bordered" border=1 align="center">
  <tr>
      <th style="width: 5%">No.</th>
          <th style="width: 20%">room_no</th>     
      <th style="width: 20%">status</th>      
      <th style="width: 10%">room_type</th> 
      <th style="width: 20%">StartDate</th>   
      <th style="width: 10%">EndDate</th>  
          <th></th>
  </tr>

<% $i=0 %>
<% @room.each do |room| %>

   <tr class="<%= cycle('odd','even') %>"> 
         <td><%= room.room_no %></td>
         <td><%= room.status %></td>         
         <td><%= room.room_type.room_type %></td>
         <td><%= room.start_date %></td>
         <td><%= room.end_date %></td>      
                 <td><%= link_to("Book Now", bookings_path(@room) ,:class=> "btn btn-info") %></td>             
  </tr> 
<% end %>
</table>
```

BookingController.rb

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController

def index
@room = Room.find(params[:id])
end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h2>Welcome to booking</h2>
<%= @room.id %>
```

Comment: Where is your `redirect_to` statement in `guest_search` action in RoomsControler.rb file?

Comment: hi.. guest_search are only use for display purpose search value using ransack search gem .so no redirect_to ..

Comment: can i know when exactly you are getting error? means in Rooms controller or in Booking controller? and in which action?

Comment: after sign_in then render index action in Bookingcontroller.rb  with room object ...but when new session start room object not found sign_in user and error  error "Active record::RecordNotFound BookingController#index" and "Could not found room without an id"

Comment: what exactly the `params[:id]` in Bokking controller? Because you are redireceting to this index action in Booking controller after successful log-in of the user. From where you are getting this id?

Comment: the params[:id] is room id that i get from roomcontroller "<td><%= link_to("Book Now", bookings_path(@room) ,:class=> "btn btn-info") %></td> " that pass to booking controller after sign_in.

Comment: Yes, here untill you click that button, room_id wont be available in Booking controller. That is the reason why you are getting the error. Means, initially after sign_in, you don't have any room_id untill you submit the search from to guest_search action for ransack search. Hope you got what i am saying.

Comment: Hope you solved the problem :)